# Excel All Possible Combinations for MacOS

Tags: excel

Is there a formula in Excel to calculate all possible combinations for multiple lists for MacOS. For instance, I am trying to draft a fantasy team and I have the following combinations:

```
(harden, westbrook, antetokounmpo)
(davis, leonard, irving, george)
(vucevic, holiday, beal, walker, conley)
(randle, collins, makkanen, williams, harrell, conley)
(paul, levine, bledsoe, gordon, young, turner, jackson, faried, horford)
(siakam, ibaka, dunn, young, collison, adams)
```

Basically, I want to figure out how to calculate all possible combinations for these 6 groups.